# How to decode hex to ASN.1 in golang

Tags: go, bitcoin

I have an ECDSA public key that that is returned to me from an HSM in ASN.1 DER format. I need to create a bitcoin compatible key 33 byte. When I print out key in `hex.EncodeToString(pubkey)` I get the following output:
`3056301006072a8648ce3d020106052b8104000a034200049bb8e80670371f45508b5f8f59946a7c4dea4b3a23a036cf24c1f40993f4a1daad1716de8bd664ecb4596648d722a4685293de208c1d2da9361b9cba74c3d1ec`

I use an online decoder here: https://holtstrom.com/michael/tools/asn1decoder.php

And it outputs:
`0x049bb8e80670371f45508b5f8f59946a7c4dea4b3a23a036cf24c1f40993f4a1daad1716de8bd664ecb4596648d722a4685293de208c1d2da9361b9cba74c3d1ec`

I can then take that and `hex.DecodeString(str)` which gives me the necessary format to input this into `addrPubKey, err := btcutil.NewAddressPubKey(bs, &chaincfg.TestNet3Params)`.

How do I decode this in golang to get the 0x049... output?

Thanks

Comment: Check out how json decoding works in Go (there are plenty of examples around). ASN1 decoding works the same: you create a struct to represent target data structure then use `asn1.Unmarshal` function (`import "encoding/asn1"`) to decode your byte slice into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing we need is to use the [encoding/asn1 package](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/asn1) from the standard library.
You only have to give go the right struct to decode into. From your link we can see that we have a `SEQUENCE` that contains another `SEQUENCE` with two `OBJECTIDENTIFIER` and a `BITSTRING`. In go this will be:

```golang
type Ids struct {
    OBi1 asn1.ObjectIdentifier
    OBi2 asn1.ObjectIdentifier
}

type PubKey struct {
    Id Ids
    Bs asn1.BitString
}
```

Now we only have to `UnMarshall` the data to this structure:

```golang
    str := `3056301006072a8648ce3d020106052b8104000a034200049bb8e80670371f45508b5f8f59946a7c4dea4b3a23a036cf24c1f40993f4a1daad1716de8bd664ecb4596648d722a4685293de208c1d2da9361b9cba74c3d1ec`

    bstring, err := hex.DecodeString(str)
    if (err != nil) {
        panic(err)
    }

    var decode PubKey
    _, err = asn1.Unmarshal(bstring, &decode)
    if (err != nil) {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(decode.Bs.Bytes))
```

Note that you don't have to encode the string to hex and back again, since Unmarshall accepts a byte array

This will print the expected result:

```
049bb8e80670371f45508b5f8f59946a7c4dea4b3a23a036cf24c1f40993f4a1daad1716de8bd664ecb4596648d722a4685293de208c1d2da9361b9cba74c3d1ec
```

Once again you probably don't need to encode to string.